# 403 Unauthorized when updating Meteor User

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm getting a 403 when trying to update a user's profile using meteor-angular. Unfortunately, it's not very descriptive -- the complete error is:

```
{ 
  details: undefined
  error: 403
  errorType: "Meteor.Error"
  message: "Access denied [403]"
  reason: "Access denied"
}
```

I'm under the impression that I don't need to add anything to the server side, but I added to try to get some visibility into what the actual update request looked like.

```
Meteor.users.deny {
  update: (userId, user, fields, modifier) ->
    console.log("meteor deny!")
    console.log(userId, user._id)
    console.log(fields, modifier)
    false
}

Meteor.users.allow {
  update: (userId, user, fields, modifier) ->
    console.log("allow", arguments)
    true
}
```

For debugging. In the logs, I see

I20150707-22:14:22.955(-6)? meteor deny!
I20150707-22:14:22.956(-6)? Hk83p9hieEBYHhzo6 Hk83p9hieEBYHhzo6
I20150707-22:14:22.956(-6)? [ 'profile' ] { '$set': { 'profile.name': 'ben', 'profile.gender': 'male' } }

Which is exactly what I would expect to see and appears to be what is required when looking at the docs -- i.e. a user is editing their own profile and the $set is using dot notation. I'm triggering the update from the client, basically using pretty plain angular. The interesting bits are

```
....
$scope.user = $meteor.object $meteor.getCollectionByName("users"), $stateParams.userId
$scope.save = () ->
  if $scope.form.$valid
    $scope.user.save({ 'profile.name': $scope.user.profile.name, 'profile.gender': $scope.user.profile.gender}).then(
      (numberOfDocs) ->
        console.log 'save successful, docs affected ', numberOfDocs
      (error) ->
        console.log 'save error ', error
    )
```

I'm sort of at a loss for what to try next. My packages are

```
meteor-platform
urigo:angular
angularui:angular-ui-router
coffeescript
mquandalle:stylus
civilframe:angular-jade
twbs:bootstrap
angularui:angular-ui-bootstrap
mquandalle:bower
tmeasday:publish-counts
aldeed:collection2
angularutils:pagination
accounts-ui
okland:accounts-phone
accounts-base
```

Comment: Does getting rid of deny and only using allow work?

Comment: Negative. I also never see the log statement in allow, even if I remove the deny

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but to fix your problem immediately, just create a method that updates a users profile server side. Just check that a user is only trying to edit his own profile.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering doing this, but that seemed silly. I've certainly spent enough time looking into this to warrant that though